# RxJava - How to Kick off Async Network call inside lambda function of subscribe? Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

Below is my exact code.  Notice that foo(o) is being called inside the subscribe lambda function. This gives strict mode error in Android. Now of course i could just spin off a thread here but is that the Rxjava way of doing things?  do I now have to think about threads again?  Would like to know my best option here. How could I do this RxJava way so that other parts of code could subscribe to the new events which would return network call response?   So essentially I am transforming one type of event MyObj into a NetObj response event via an Async response.

```
 public static final PublishSubject<MyObj> myObjSubject = PublishSubject.create();
  public static final Observable<MyObj> observable = myObjSubject.asObservable();


protected CompositeSubscription myCompositeSubs = new CompositeSubscription();

myCompositeSubs.add(
            observable.subscribe((MyObj o) -> {
                 // `. Update UI with MyObject and 
                 // 2. Kick off network call which will return JsonResponse type object which I would like to possibly process here and also publish to let others respond to it.
                 foo(o);  // $$$$$ million dollar question what if I am kicking off something long running here?
            }));


private void foo(MyObj o){

// long running request.  How to kick off long running from here? 
  JsonRespons resp = RestAdapter.makeQuest(o.url);
  // I want this JsonResponse object to be an even others can listen for. I don't want to just process it right here.

}
```

Update: Just to clarify what I am trying to do is listen for a data event MyObject inside a class (Android Fragment). Once I get this I want to do TWO things, update the UI synchronously with MyObject which is something I want to consume and not just transform. But I also want to kick off a long running request. A network call that gives back JsonObject response. This I might process in the same fragment when it comes back or I might want other classes be able to listen for this event.  So I am not observing MyObject solely to then make the network call and get the response back. I need to do both operations, one sync the other async.

Comment: Looks like this type of issue might have been discussed here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to use an RxJava operator like `flatMap`. Take a look [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) if you want more documentation, but `flatMap` allows you to take one Observable of a type (your `Observable<MyObj>`) and return an Observable of another type (in this case it can be `Observable<Void>` or maybe `Observable<Boolean>` if you want to know if your long running request completes or not).

Take a look at this code:

```
Subscription sub = observable.flatMap((MyObj o) -> {
      // this will be run on your subscribeOn thread -- in background
      return Observable.just(foo(o));
    }).subscribe(aVoid -> {
      // we have completed both operations here, emissions will be 
      // on our observeOn() thread
    });
```

Where your `foo(MyObj)` function is now structured as:

```
private Void foo(MyObj o) {
    // long running stuff
    return null;
}
```

It's important to make the return type `Void` instead of `void` so that we are able to use the `flatMap` operator and to get an `Observable<Void>` returned.

All of your long running `foo()` operation will run on your `subscribeOn()` thread, along with your initial observable, and once the operation has completed, it will emit a `Void` item to your `subscribe()` on your `observeOn()` thread (this can be your main thread in Android if you want to notify the UI).

**Updated to allow UI work in the flatMap call:**

Note: this assumes that the first `observable` has defined `subscribeOn()` on a background thread and `observeOn()` to `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

```
Subscription sub = observable.flatMap((MyObj o) -> {
      // << do stuff with MyObj to UI HERE >> 
      return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(foo(o)))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }).subscribe(aVoid -> {
      // foo() has completed, we're back on the UI thread
    });
```

If you want to do something with a JsonResponse, you would change the `foo()` function to return that instead of `Void`, then you would be able to work with the result of `foo()` on the UI thread.

**Update 2:** change `Observable.create()` to `Observable.defer()` to make it cleaner.

Comment: Just to clarify I'm in a single class (Android Fragment), and I want to process this in such a way that I can take some synchronous action upon receiving MyObject but then also want to make the Async call and upon completion or error take some other action.

Comment: I have Singleton with various observers and subjects but let's see if I return Objservable.just(foo) that would work within this one class but what if I wanted the response to be visible outside the fragment? I want the mapped to JSonResponse for example. So outside classes I want them to be able to consume listen for JSonResponse .  How do outsider listeners tap into the JSonResponse object?

Comment: So I want the Fragment to be able to take some action on MyObj , and launch this Async operation which will return say a JsonResponse.  its that response that I want to be able to listen for or observe as stream.  I might want to handle it in the fragment that kicked it off or somewhere else.  So what I am saying is that a single class will use the MyObj class for say updating the UI, and it will kick off the async.  Once that return I want it to sort of be published or there be a way to listen to the JsonResponse type of the stream.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify more the the two operations one sync and on async that I am trying to do within the Fragment.

Comment: See my updated response. Changing the return of `foo()` to JsonResponse will allow any subscribers to the `PublishSubject` to act on the emitted values in your `subscribe()` calls. So you could either have multiple `Subscription`s to listen to the subject, or you could setup a callback mechanism that will notify any listeners of the JsonResponse in your `subscribe()`